# Setka - Complete grid using clues and sudoku-style logic; Theme - Halftime

Tags: logical-deduction, word, wordplay, sudoku, logic-grid

This is a Setka puzzle; you can find more (along with a more detailed explanation of the rules) at our website, linked from our profile.

How to play Setka, the short version:

Answer each clue using only Puzzle Letters and vowels.

Clue answers, minus vowels and duplicate letters, go in the corresponding boxes in the grid. Only Puzzle Letters go in the grid!

Puzzle Letters can be entered forward/backward/up/down/L-shape, but not jumbled. They also cannot repeat in a row or column.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the completed grid:

> [image]

However, I could not solve all the clues. The following were enough to fill out:

> 2: FeeT
>  3: FaMe
>  9: L (roman number)
>  10: THeLMa (and Louise)
>  11: FiT(bit)

Here are some I figured out after completing the grid.

> 5: HoT

Comment: great!  This is exactly how it is played - a back and forth with the clues and the grid, each assisting the other.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Answers:

> 1. HeLM
>  2. FeeT
>  3. FaMe
>  4. FeMaLe
>  5. HoT
>  6. HaL
>  7. HuT
>  8. (F)ootball (M)adness
>  9. L
>  X. THeLMa
>  J. FiT

The grid:

> ```
>  1 2 2 3 4
>  1 5 5 3 4
>  1 6 6 7 4
>  8 8 9 7 X
>  J J X X X
> ```
>
> The $9$ is L, and the $1$'s force the $8$'s, which in turn force the $J$'s:
>
> ```
>  1 2 2 3 4
>  1 5 5 3 4
>  1 6 6 7 4
>  F M L 7 X
>  T F X X X
> ```
>
> Next, the $X$'s and $7$'s can be placed:
>
> ```
>  1 2 2 3 4
>  1 5 5 3 4
>  1 6 6 T 4
>  F M L H T
>  T F M L H
> ```
>
> Now the $6$'s, $5$'s and $2$'s can be placed:
>
> ```
>  1 T F 3 4
>  1 H T 3 4
>  1 L H T 4
>  F M L H T
>  T F M L H
> ```
>
> And the $1$'s, $3$'s and $4$'s fall into place:
>
> ```
>  H T F M L
>  L H T F M
>  M L H T F
>  F M L H T
>  T F M L H
> ```

Comment: Well done!  BTW: our answer for 8 is Fear Of Missing Out (FOMO / FM), but love your answer too!